# Which is considered more valuable for faculty job applications, teaching experience or participation in conferences?

Tags: career-path, teaching, conference, tenure-track, faculty-application

As a PhD student from top university, I have the opportunity of having a minor called "teaching minor". For me, I am personally mostly interested in mathematical application into material science while I am very interested in getting tenured faculty positions.

Actually, I am more interested in going to a lot of conference and trying to advertise or publicize the result of my research and I am worried that committed teaching during the teaching minor program would render me less experience in conference or slows down my research progress....

Any suggestion on my situation? Shall I pursue the teaching minor, or minor in mathematics as it is my research and personal interest? Or shall I do exhaust myself trying to do both?

Comment: I would need a few clarifications to answer that. (1) what has your choice of a minor (and do you even have that at graduate level?) to do with whether you go to more conferences or teach more? (2) when you say "go to more conferences", do you mean that you would produce more high-quality research and publish it at those conferences, or really just "go" there without paper for networking?

Comment: (3) Are you more interested in research universities or more teaching-oriented faculties? I am assuming the former, but it would help to make this clear.

Comment: @XLeitix:  Depending on research area, one needn't necessarily produce more research in order to attend more conferences.  When conference talks are not considered publications, it's perfectly acceptable to give talks on the same research at several different conferences.

Comment: @TaraB I know. That's why I think the OP should clarify what he means (do more research, or just go to more conferences). The former is clearly helpful for your research track record, the latter may be only marginally helpful.

Comment: Yes, but the way you phrased it was rooted in computer science conference culture.  In mathematics, we go to conferences and present the same research multiple times to help publicise it (which I wouldn't consider quite the same thing as networking).

Comment: My situation is like this: I have algorithms constructed and programmed for material scientist and I want to attend more conference to publicize my algorithm... I am not sure whether too much teaching would inhibit my progress... Or could I substitute teaching with conference talks? Thank you:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where do you want to work? Research universities want people who do research, publish, go to conferences,  and can tolerably teach, in that order.

Small liberal arts colleges want people who can teach and who do enough research to keep up with the field.

These are rough generalizations. There's no right answer here.

Comment: I want to work in research universities and focus on research as my first priority... If I have zero teaching experience, but good research results (say 10+ papers and 100+ citations). Does that harm? Thank you:)

Comment: No, we'd use your job talk as a proxy for your teaching. If you can give a good job talk, that'd more than make up for a teaching minor certificate.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. So I think the conclusion is that I shall push all myself to get better research results then?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot assume that just because you want to work in a research university that 1) there will be a job opening the year you are on the market and 2) that there aren't even more qualified candidates than yourself. You should leave yourself open to the contingency of teaching at a non-research university. These things are difficult to predict, and it's your life and career in the balance.